# ata1.00 errors about a SSD

Tags: kernel, ssd, sata

I have a new SSD, Crucial BX500, on my laptop Acer ES1-732. I have installed a Debian Bullseye distribution.

I often have some ata errors like these:

```
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 526848 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0


ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ata1.00: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 17
         res 40/00:84:b0:0f:cc/00:00:1b:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ata1.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
ata1: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake DevExch }
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4050000 action 0xe frozen


ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ata1.00: cmd 61/08:b8:f8:9e:cc/00:00:1b:00:00/40 tag 23 ncq dma 4096 out
         res 50/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ata1: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake DevExch }
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x800000 SErr 0x4050000 action 0xe frozen


ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:88:48:09:09/00:00:26:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq dma 4096 in
         res 40/00:84:10:09:09/00:00:26:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata1: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake DevExch }
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x2060000 SErr 0x4050000 action 0xe frozen
```

I wonder why there are theses errors, and how to solve the problem. I tried to run `badblocks` and it didn't report any bad block.

The computer needs the following kernel parameter: `pci=nocrs`, to avoid a freeze during grub install.

Once installed, I tried to boot with and without this parameter, and it seems there are more often ata errors with `pci=nocrs`.

Despite these errors, the Linux system seems to work correctly, and I have never seen any crash or freeze, except when installing grub, but it also occurs with the hard drive that came with the laptop, not only with the new SSD.

I tried some kernel parameters: `libata.force=noncq` and `libata.dma=0`, but it didn't solve the problem, and strongly reduced the speed of the SSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by updating the firmware of the SSD.

Crucial website said there was no firmware update for this drive, but I installed Windows 10 and the "Crucial Storage Executive" software. And the software found a firmware update for my SSD.